# Встроенные методы, чтобы сделать объект изменяемым

Tags: python, c++, объекты, ссылки

Есть ли в Python встроенные методы, чтобы сделать объект mutable? Что-то вроде `std::reference_wrapper` в C++. Нужно для передачи в обработчик сигнала внешней неглобальной переменной.

Желаемое поведение:

```
def foo(x):
    x = 43

x = 42
print(x) # 42
foo(magic_tools.make_mutable(x))
print(x) # 43
```

Пример на C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
void foo(T x) {
    x = 43;
}

int main() {
    auto x = 42;
    std::cout << x << '\n'; // 42
    foo<int&>(std::reference_wrapper<int>{x}); // or foo<int&>(x);
    std::cout << x << '\n'; // 43
}
```

Имеется в виду сделать новый mutable wrapper объект с переопределённым assignment, а не изменить свойства старого; под обработчиком сигнала понимаю произвольную функцию, которую можно установить через `signal.signal(signum, handler)`.

Comment: И всё-таки непонятно, что вы хотите. Кейс использования непонятен. Можно, например, передавать в функцию список, элементы списка можно менять как хотите.

Comment: @CrazyElf можно, но при передаче списка из 1 элемента надо изменять код функции на `x[0] = 43`. Можно без изменения кода `foo` это сделать? Максимум с декорированием

Comment: @CrazyElf нашёл похожий ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/45113210

Comment: Ну вот походе простого варианта нет, только как в том ответе. А в чём проблема поменять питоновскую функцию - это же интерпретатор, обычно всё в исходниках есть что на питоне написано.